# Run Tomcat with Maven and Eclipse - Unknown lifecycle phase

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I am using Eclipse Helios,Tomcat Server 7. I have build my project using Maven. When I try to build my project, I get the below error in Eclipse.

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO]                                                                         
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Building encore Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 0.095s
 [INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 06 18:17:55 IST 2012
 [INFO] Final Memory: 2M/36M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or    a    goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Please let me know what is wrong in my code and kindly point to right directions. I need to figure it out ASAP.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.encore</groupId>
<artifactId>encore</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>encore Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>      
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>     
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<finalName>encore</finalName>   
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.9</version>  
        <configuration>
                 <server>mytomcatserver</server>
                 <path>/encore</path>
                 <url>http://localhost:8080</url>
                 <username>admin</username>
                 <password>admin</password>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
 </project>
```

This is my pom.xml. I am trying to Run my application as Run as-> mvn build from eclipse.

Comment: We cannot see what's wrong in your code since you don't show us the code... But it looks like you have invoked this like this: `mvn build` which isn't a legal command.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you've accidentally set the wrong goal when trying to build from Eclipse. Edit your Maven "Run as.." settings like so:

[image]

Note the `clean install` which will run the Maven commands to clean your build and do a full build and install into the local repository.

Answer (score 9):

Try `mvn install` instead of `mvn build`. `build` is not a valid option for Maven. You can find a list of valid options in the error message above.

If you just want to compile the sources, try `mvn compile` but that will usually produce an incorrect result when you have more than one `pom.xml` file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You should build : install  , not build : mvn install ,not start with mvn ...

Comment: cant believe i made this mistake!

Answer (score 1):

All ides ( Eclipse, Intellij etc.) have some problems with maven build, instead of using bundled maven component, use command-line maven. 
In command line ( windows or linux console does not matter.) mvn clean, then mvn install will fix your problem. Command line usage can be change your view point of maven.

Answer (score 1):

It is most probable you set incorrect goals in the configuration when you ran "run as" "Maven build" and now can't change it.

Right click on the project -> run as -> Run configurations.

A picture to illustrate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry65K.png

This will bring back up the window you first had on your first build and you can then follow the instructions of the more experienced contributors above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Error**:  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.**LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException** 
 For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/**LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException**

**Solution** : Unknown lifecycle phase or wrong goal **example**:First I am using "clean package tea-container-test:tomcat-test -P "XXX" -e" as goal , then I changed a goal as "test -P XXX" , then It works perfectly,so **Please check , your goal is right or wrong**.
"Creates a new exception to indicate that the specified lifecycle phase is not defined by any known lifecycle".

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, uninstall the GIT bash and install again. This will resolve EnvVar issue is any.

If still not solved, please check with your commands. Copy and paste your commands from notepad and this should work