# Compiling java using Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, compilation

When I compiling my java file using maven the error exist....
..........

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.dbs.epodsms:ePOD_SMS_RCVR_SNDR_GLOBE:jar:2.0-RELEASE
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 23, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ePOD_SMS_RCVR_SNDR 2.0-RELEASE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.172s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 03 15:05:03 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Compile". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

...........
WHAT WILL BE THE SPECIFIC ERROR.. ANYONE? im using eclipse indigo(IDE)

Answer (score 2):

You have used "Compile" as the lifecycle phase, maven expects the value "compile" as shown by the error

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Compile". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, **compile**, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Answer (score 1):

As Mehul said, your Maven lifecycle phase is incorrect.  To display and change your Maven goals in Eclipse, see Duncan Jones' answer to this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251669/run-tomcat-with-maven-and-eclipse-unknown-lifecycle-phase).

You probably want to change "Compile" to "compile" or even to "clean install".